# How do I exclude babel plugins from certain environments?

Tags: plugins, lodash, babeljs

I have .babelrc configured as something like this

```js
{
    "env" : {
        "test": {
          "plugins": [some other plugins...] //but not lodash
        }
       "plugins": ["lodash", some other plugins ...]
}
```

but this configuration isn't working. If i gave at cli `BABEL_ENV=test <command>` still lodash comes with it.

I even tried `"exclude": ["babel-plugin-lodash"]` in test. what is the correct way to exclude `lodash` from test enviroment but not in default run ?
I am trying to workaround [this issue](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul/issues/116).

I tried work around suggested there but I want `lodash` in the default run too.Here default mean without `BABEL_ENV=<env>` in command line.

Comment: `"exclude": ["bable-plugin-lodash"]` contains a typo. Should be _babel_.

Comment: typo was just here not in actual code

Answer (score 0):

You need to ommit "babel-plugin-" when excluding iodash.

exclude": ["Iodash"]

More here: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9182